# LSTM model constantly underpredicts

Tags: time-series, lstm, prediction, bias

I have a dataset that consists of temperature measurements. The temperature is increasing as time goes by. I have developed different RNN models (LSTM,BiLSTM,GRU,BiGRU) to predict future values of these measurements. Although the RMSE and MAE values are below the thermocouple's measurement uncertainty, my models always underpredict as shown in the image. Why do you think this might happen? Can I somehow correct it? The structure of my models is simple, I only add a dropout later of 20% after each LSTM or GRU layer and before the dense output layer.
Also, do you think the underprediction is an issue even if it is less than the thermocouple's measurement uncertainty?[image]
Thank you in advance!